# springboot websocket with JPA NullPointerException

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, spring-data-jpa, spring-websocket

I'm wreting a SpringBoot web service use websocket to send message to client and using JPA to save data. 
in project I use a thread to create a data ,and then use JPA to save it ,use Websocket to show data. But it doesn't work with a NullPointExecption.
this is my code:

```
@RestController
@ServerEndpoint("/websocket")
public class CrawlingController {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrawlingController.class);
    @Autowired
    private SimulateDataRepository simulateDataRepository;


    private static GlobalStatus globalStatus = GlobalStatus.getInstance();

    private Session session;
    private static CopyOnWriteArraySet<CrawlingController> crawlingControllers =
            new CopyOnWriteArraySet<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws Exception {
        this.session = session;
        crawlingControllers.add(this);
        String message = dataCrawling();

    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        for (CrawlingController controller : crawlingControllers)
            sendMessage(message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose() {
        crawlingControllers.remove(this);
        if (crawlingControllers.size() == 0)
            end();
       session=null;
       end();
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) throws IOException {
        this.session.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
    }

    public void onError(Session session, Throwable error) {
        logger.error(error.getMessage());
        System.out.println("websocket found something error!");
    }


    @RequestMapping("/start")
    public String dataCrawling() throws Exception {
        if (!globalStatus.isDataCrawling) {
            Process process = null;
            synchronized (globalStatus) {
                process = Utils.crawling();
                globalStatus.crawlingProcss = process;
                globalStatus.isDataCrawling = true;
            }
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    stuffSimulate(bufferedReader);
                } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage());
                }
            }).start();
            return "start Finish!";
        } else return "faild";
    }

    public void stuffSimulate(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException, ParseException {
        line = reader.readLine();
        while (globalStatus.isDataCrawling) {
                    SimulateData simulateData = new SimulateData();
                    .... ...
                    simulateData.setData(data.toString());
                    this.saveAndShow(simulateData);
                }
            } 
        }
    }

    private void saveAndShow(SimulateData simulateData) throws IOException {
        simulateData = simulateDataRepository.saveAndFlush(simulateData);
        SummaryData summaryData = SimulateService.obtainSummary(simulateData);
        onMessage(summaryData.printSummary(),this.session);


        summaryData.sout();
    }
}
```

simulateDataRepository can be work when i use http://localhost:8080/start.
the mysql can get data.
But it cna't be work when i use websocket!!!
The error meaasge said that:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cn.linhos.controller.CrawlingController.saveAndShow(CrawlingController.java:293)
    at cn.linhos.controller.CrawlingController.stuffSimulate(CrawlingController.java:172)
    at cn.linhos.controller.CrawlingController.lambda$dataCrawling$0(CrawlingController.java:104)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

why simulateDataRepository can't saveAndFlush when websocket but can do it   when i use "/start"?
how should i do to make websocket work ?

Comment: You are keeping state in a singleton... What do you think will happen to the `Session` instance vatiable after 10 sessions are opened.... Which `Session` remains. Never keep state in a singleton.

Comment: I need to keeping  global state to save state and prevent something happend again. I know this is a bad model ,but i couldn't find a batter one. this not a main problem, my confuse is how should i eliminate NullPointerException? thank you! @M. Deinum

Comment: No you don't... You need to find another way, you cannot keep global state. Your design is flawed and basically the root of your problem.

Comment: so, which way should i do, to prevent someone do something again , and send they some param that create in anothery method when they need? in my opinion ,they may do something that need they finish another action, and something they couldn't do again except they undo the action they have done before.@M. Deinum

Comment: Just pass the session in the method or create a scoped proxy that holds it, never keep it in a singleton. I also don't get your `sendMessage` method the way you call it that is. You have a perfectly fine `Session` in the method,  but decide to discard it?

Comment: i need to store some param that belong project ,not only for the websocket。how holding these param is my main problem, the session couldn't hold all param, and i have to prevent some method start more time。 this session just take me to know where should i send my message, but couldn't prevent somebody use some method thart they had run. @M. Deinum

Comment: The problem is you are storing state in a **singleton** whereas the state changes per request/session. Each time overriding the other, so gain your main problem is you are keeping state that you shouldn't be keeping.